# How to convert (ROS) "geometry_msgs/Point" to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2?

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

I'm a student studying LIDAR algorithm. I have a LIDAR code that subscribes to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`.
and I'm receiving `geometry_msgs/Point` data now. I wanna convert `geometry_msgs/Point` to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`. And I wanna apply the code I wrote. Please tell me the `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` type function in c++ !!
And there are `width` and `height`, and so on in `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`. How do I convert it? I'm curious because `geometry_msgs/Point` doesn't have them.

If it's `sensor_msgs/LaserScan`, I've converted it, but I'm not sure about `geometry_msgs/Point`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is unclear. Please rewrite it, giving more context, and preferably providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud`, which [contains a vector](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud.html) of `geometry_msgs::Point32`.

Then add your points to this msg and you call the method `convertPointCloudToPointCloud2`from [point_cloud_conversion.hpp](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/sensor_msgs/include/sensor_msgs/point_cloud_conversion.hpp)

```
static inline bool convertPointCloudToPointCloud2(
  const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud & input,
  sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 & output)
```

to get the `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`

or you could try creating a `pcl::PointCloud2` and then convert using  either the method `fromPCL` or `moveFromPCL` from [pcl_conversions](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/ros2/pcl_conversions/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I convert geomety_msgs::Point32 to sensor_msgs::PointCloud, there's something called  ChannelFloat32[] channels in sensor_msgs::PointCloud, how should I define it?

Comment: from the [message definition](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/ChannelFloat32.html), this is a way to add some other data to the point cloud, like `intensity`, `RGB` data. You need to add the `name` of the filed and the `float32[ ]` values. Remember that the size of `ChannelFloat32[ ] channels` has to be the same from `geometry_msgs/Point32[ ] points`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to create a pcl PointCloud2 struct, fill it with the geometry_msgs/Point data and adapt width accordingly.
If you have a vector `points` of type `geometry_msgs/Point` you can do the following.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tmp(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
tmp->width = 0;
tmp->height = 1;
tmp->is_dense = false;
tmp->points.resize(tmp->width * tmp->height);
tmp->header.frame_id = _your_frame;

for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
{
    pcl::PointXYZ pt;
    pt.x = points.at(i).x;
    pt.y = points.at(i).y;
    pt.z = points.at(i).z;
    tmp->points.push_back(pt);
    tmp->width++;
}
```

And now you can convert this PCL Pointcloud to Pointcloud2 using the known methods.